# GridView.FindControl() - works, but not properly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I have the the GridView's column looking like that:

```
         <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Opcje">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Accept" ID="AcceptBtn" CommandName="Accept"/>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Deny" ID="DenyBtn" CommandName="Deny"/> 
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
```

while a new row is being created, I want to change both LinkButton's CommandArgument property:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        ((LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("AcceptBtn")).CommandArgument = myFiles[fileIndex].Name;
        ((LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("DenyBtn")).CommandArgument = myFiles[fileIndex].Name;
    }
```

The problem is, the code seems to be not changing anything, when I click on the AcceptBtn, the code below is invoked:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Accept")
        {
            string ss = (string)e.CommandArgument;
            ...
        }
    }
```

**ss = "". Why ?** If the page is PostedBack, both CommandArguments are cleared ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `CommandArgument` in the `RowDataBound` event instead of `RowCreated`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use rowdatabound event like..

```
 protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        ((LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("AcceptBtn")).CommandArgument = myFiles[fileIndex].Name;
        ((LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("DenyBtn")).CommandArgument = myFiles[fileIndex].Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

where do you set

```
myFiles[fileIndex].Name;
```

and each of its components?